# calculating O(n) when computer speed is doubled

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity

1. Say  an algorithm of O(n) is solved on a computer with speed X.
   Now this same algo when used on a computer of 2X speed can solve a problem of size 2N in the same time.
2. Now if we have an algo of O(logn) on a computer with speed X
   How do i calculate the  size of the problem that can be solved in the same time on a computer with 2X speed.
3. Similarly for an o(n^2).

This is not any homework problem or such.
Just curiosity as the book I was reading says for question 2 above it is O(n^2) and I don't get it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let n be the current amount of work handled, and m be the amount of work handled if the speed is doubled. See discussion here:
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/248306/time-complexity-why-does-doubling-the-speed-given-this-improvement

```
For O(log(n)):

log(m)/log(n) = 2
log(m)=2*log(n)
log(m)=log(n^2)  =>  m=n^2

For O(n^2):

m^2/n^2 = 2  =>  m = sqrt(2)*n
```

Answer (score 3):

These kind of estimations are only possible if you know the big-theta of the run time, and then only if the problem size is large enough.

For 2) `2*log(n) = log(n^2)`

For 3) `2*n^2 = (n*sqrt(2))^2`

Answer (score 1):

Big O notation doesn't rely on computer speed, it just describes the algorithmic time complexity. Something where you have to iterate through an array twice will always be 2N, if you put it on a computer that is twice as fast it will still be of 2N time complexity even if in reality it completes twice as quickly. That is the beauty of the notation, that it is independent of processor speed.

Comment: Some don't like to hear it, but this is correct.  Big O doesn't concern itself with exact run times, only with the trend as problems get larger.  There are lower order effects that can dominate for smaller `n`.  In fact a loop of n and a loop of 2n are *both* O(n).

Comment: Yeah I went for the 2N thing since in this case he was talking about 2 times computer speed and I though just putting N might make the answer confusing in that context but you are absolutely correct.